# Do action if button clicked 3 times [javascript]

Tags: javascript, html, button

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick = 'click1()'> </button>
</body>
  <script>
  var one
    function click1(){
      one = one + 1;
    }
  if (one == 3){
    document.write('yes')
  }
  </script>
</html>
```

Here is an example JS / HTML. How can I write yes if the button is clicked three times?. This code would work in python and other languages. How can I do this in JS?

Comment: Pretty sure this code wouldn't work in any other language. First of all, you need to give `one` an initial value (`0`) and secondly, you need to put the `if` and `document.write` inside the click event handler function. As it is now, it will only run once, on page load.

Comment: If they click it a 4th time should it still say 'yes' or should it reset?

Comment: Additionally, `one` is not a good name for a variable that is actually a counter - it's misleading since the value will change when the user interacts with the button. Readable code and logical naming of variables is a very important part of programming! When writing a program, I probably spend more time thinking about function and variables name than I do about algorithms and data structures lol.

Comment: As a side note: don't use `document.write()`, especially in code that runs after the DOM is ready. There are better ways to manipulate the DOM, check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.

- First of all you should set a default to the variable, otherwise it will be declared as undefined.
- Second you should put your if in the same function.
- Third you should call your functions with the brackets in your html => 'click1()'

I also recommend making some changes

- make your variable a let instead of a var.
- use typesafe checks with 3 equal signs

```html
<html>
<body>
<button onclick = 'click1()'> </button>
<script>
  let one = 0;
  function click1(){
    one += 1;
    if (one === 3){
      document.write('yes')
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code have syntax and logical errors

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick='click1()'>click here </button>
<script>
  var one = 0;
    function click1(){
      one = one + 1;
      if (one == 3){
        alert("here");
        }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

after three clicks you will again have to reset variable `one` in if statement

```
if (one == 3){
  alert("here");
  one = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="click1()">Click</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    var one = 0;
    const click1 = () => { if (++one === 3) document.write('yes') };
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var one = 0;
function click1() { 
  one++
  if (one == 3) {
    console.log('yes');
    one = 0
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick ='click1()'> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the brackets on the function call on your button. Try: onclick='click1()'

Comment: Nah I tried that, that is not the problem

Comment: Your if statement should also be inside the click1 function. Otherwise it's never reached.

Comment: @red_panda It was *one* of the problems with your code

Comment: I'm only a beginner in javascript, true @Lennholm

Answer (score 0):

You could use an approach like below. See the code comments for details:

```js
// Reference to the DOM elements
const countEl = document.querySelector('#count-el');
const buttonEl = document.querySelector('button');

// Init a counter variable and return a function that increments it
const increment = (() => {
  let i = 1;

  return () => i++;
})();

// The click event listener
buttonEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Increment the count and update the UI based on if current click count is 3
  if (increment() === 3) {
    countEl.textContent = 'yes';
  }
});
```

```html
<span id="count-el"></span>
<br />
<button>Click 3 times</button>
```